# Обмен данными между таблицами Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Как реализовать обмен данными между таблицами `Google Spreadsheet`?

Для наглядности визуализировал все на картинке:

[image]
Таблицы находятся в разных документах.

При редактировании ячеек информация должна обновиться в другой таблице.
Соответствие строк должно соблюдаться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для этого не нужен Apps Script, задача решается встроенными функциями [`importrange`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=ru) и [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=ru). А именно,  `importrange` включает часть одной таблицы в другую, например

```
=importrange("...", "Sheet5!I1:M10")
```

где в ... надо поместить ссылку на другую таблицу, взяв её из адресной строки браузера. При первом использовании понадобится подтвердить разрешение на импорт данных.

Затем, выбрать только нужные данные посредством `query` (синтакс подобен SQL):

```
=query(importrange("...", "Sheet5!I1:M10"); "select Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7 where Col8 = 'В таблицу 1'")
```

Отмечу, что Col3, например, означает третий столбец импортированного куска таблицы. В этом примере выбраны только строки, где в 8-м столбце указано *В таблицу 1*.